# PHP/MYSQL Selecting a MAX value and using it as an inserted value

Tags: php, mysql, insert, max

I have a small database project using HTML forms and PHP code. It is working perfectly except the last part. Basically, I have my database connection setup and working in my PHP, and upon hitting the Add button it should insert values from the form to the database. My instructor said that due to table constraints it has to be inserted in a certain order, basically address table first and then staff table. IF I comment out the staff part of code, my successful confirmation page appears and the address appears in the database every time with an auto incremented address_id. The issue is that I'm supposed to query for a MAX(Address_id) and use that for inserting the staff part, as it uses address_id as a foreign key. When I do that, I get a foreign key constraint error on update cascade. If I completely pull out the INSERT staff code, and put a 'debug' to print the MAX(address_id), it prints correctly. I just can't get it to insert to the staff table correctly so that everything from my form creates a staff record. Here is the code:

```
    $userQuery = "INSERT INTO address (address, district, city_id, postal_code, phone) 
              VALUES ('$address', '$district', '$city', '$postal_code', '$phone') ";

$addressResult = mysqli_query($connect, $userQuery);
if (!$addressResult) 
{
    die("Could not successfully run query ($userQuery) from $db: " .    
    mysqli_error($connect) );
}



$maxQuery = "SELECT MAX(address_id) FROM address";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $maxQuery);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
if (!$result) 
{
    die("Could not successfully run query ($userQuery) from $db: " .    
    mysqli_error($connect) );
}
/**else 
{ 

    print ("<p>Average hourly wage:".$row['MAX(address_id)']."</p>");

}**/


$userQuery1 = "INSERT INTO staff (first_name, last_name, address_id, email, store_id)
               VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$row', '$email', '$store_id')";
$staffResult =  mysqli_query($connect, $userQuery1);
if (!$staffResult) 
{
    die("Could not successfully run query ($userQuery1) from $db: " .   
    mysqli_error($connect) );
}   
else
{
    print(" <h1>New Staff Record Added!</h1>");
    print ("<p>The following record was added:</p>");
    print("<table border='0'>
            <tr><td>First Name</td><td>$first_name</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Last Name</td><td>$last_name</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email</td><td>$email</td></tr>      
            <tr><td>Store ID</td><td>$store_id</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Address</td><td>$address</td></tr>
            <tr><td>City</td><td>$city</td></tr>
            <tr><td>District</td><td>$district</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Postal Code</td><td>$postal_code</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Phone</td><td>$phone</td></tr>
            </table>");
}
```

Comment: Rather than using `MAX()` as well, just use `mysqli_insert_id`. That'll return the ID from the previous INSERT statement

Comment: After you do an `INSERT`, you can use `mysqli_insert_id($connect)` to get the ID that was assigned. You can also use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the MySQL query to get that. `MAX(address_id)` is a poor way to do it.

Comment: so would I be able to put the mysqli_insert_id($connect) into my insert query for the staff table? and that would insert the last created ID from the first insert?

Comment: You would want to set it to a variable first: $last_insert_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);

Comment: Ok I did that and I can return it successfully, so that works well. I just keep getting that constraint error when I load the web page. I'll have to look at the tables in MySQL workbench and see if I'm missing something with the foreign keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling the correct associative index. You are just calling the array:

```
$userQuery1 = "INSERT INTO staff (first_name, last_name, address_id, email, store_id) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '{$row['MAX(address_id)']}', '$email', '$store_id')";
```

Comment: I've added curly braces to the array. Try it now.

Comment: Ok, I just applied that change and I think that will work, thank you. I'm still getting the constraint error but I think I might need to make a change to how it's being associated between the two tables: Just using '1' as a test value in each field

Comment: Could not successfully run query (INSERT INTO staff (first_name, last_name, address_id, email, store_id) VALUES ('1', '1', '', '1', '1')) from sakila: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sakila`.`staff`, CONSTRAINT `fk_staff_address` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `address` (`address_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)